# sed + change small and capital letter

Tags: sed

I have the following

```
 echo "<x>small<X>capital" | sed s'/<x>/WORD/'g
```

How to change sed syntax in order to replace x and X with WORD

in this sed . sed replace only the small letter x

THX
yael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 echo "<x>small<X>capital" | sed s'/<[Xx]>/WORD/'g
```

Answer (score 1):

In GNU `sed`, you can use a case-insensitive modifier:

```
echo "<x>small<X>capital" | sed 's/<x>/WORD/ig'
```